# why does dreamweaver generate persistent mysql connections but not clean up after itself?

Tags: php, mysql

As in title:

Using deamweaver 11.5 build 5315

If you create a connection through the GUI, rather than coding it yourself, it uses the `mysql_pconnect()` function to connect to the database.

Later, when you include this connection file on one of your pages and run a query, it adds `mysql_free_result()` calls to the bottom of the page but doesn't add a `mysql_close()` call for the persistent connection it opened earlier.

This managed to bring down a site I'm developing with only about 4 people using it until I noticed the 'p' in `mysql_pconnect()`

So is this something I've done wrong or does Dreamweaver do this on purpose, and when / how does it clean up the connection if ever?

EDIT: and is it best practise or not (I'm thinking not)?

EDIT: dreamweaver 11.5 not 1.5, sorry

Comment: I know that some versions of dreamweaver add the mysql_close() at the bottom of the file. Is it not there?

Comment: nope. also, according to the manual, mysql_close() doesn't close persistent connections (just found that out)... http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php

Comment: Then, yes. It is a bad practise. Some versions of MySQL also don't have very good handling of persistent connections and cause them to slowly pile up and choke the system.

Comment: yeah that's exactly what happened with our site, mysql got too many connections as they took forever to time out, and 4 people on the site at the same time was enough to bring it down. annoyingly, according to the docs on mysql_pconnect(), it should just pick up the same one and use it again - but it seemed to be generating more instead. :@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_pconnect makes a persistent connection.
mysql_connect makes a "normal" connection, where the socket is closed when the script is finished.

If you are making a lot of queries in a small amount of time, you should go with mysql_pconnect. However if that is not the case, you should stick with mysql_connect.

Comment: well, that's what I ended up doing. After thinking about it, I realised that DW probably uses persistent connections by default either because it *used* to be a good way to do it, or because oracle and the others seem to fare better with them. long story short, if you ever get too many connections, remove the p from mysql_pconnect and relax.